# Space after symbol and the letters after the symbol

Tags: tables, spacing

I got this table.

```
\begin{table}[h]

\caption{Table caption}
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}

    \begin{tabular}{ l | l | l | l }
        \hline
        Something [Nr] & $\Delta y [m/s]$ & $\Delta x  [s]$ & $a [m/s^2]$ \\
        \hline
        1.          & 0.6      & 2.4847 & 0.24148    \\
        2.          & 0.43     & 1.7630 & 0.24390    \\
        3.          & 0.38     & 1.5829 & 0.24007    \\
        4.          & 0.30     & 1.1617 & 0.25824    \\
        5.          & 0.45     & 1.8024 & 0.24967    \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

The problem is that I have used some symbols which I cannot make a space after. Also the letter after the symbol cant have a space after it.

For example from the code I want a \Delta symbol like this

Δy [m/s]

Instead I get this:

Δy[m/s]

Also I wonder how I get it like this if I would need to at another time:

Δ y [m/s]

Comment: What's a `1` type column?

Comment: @Sverre -- that's "ell", not "one".  wretched fonts apparently don't make a reasonable distinction.

Comment: not mentioned in the answers, but it seems you must have gotten an error in the log about `$` being inserted.  that's a dead giveaway that math mode isn't being invoked properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Math expressions (like greek letters, variables, and superscripting) need to be delimited with dollar signs, as in `$\Delta y$ [m/s]`, for example. Also, in general (non-math mode), adding a `{}` after a macro prevents subsequent space from being absorbed.

Although in this case (math mode), explicit space (`~` or `\,`) would be required if you wanted space between the delta and the variable.  Compare, for example, `\Delta\,y` (space added) to `\Delta x` (no space added) in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Table caption}
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}

    \begin{tabular}{ l | l | l | l }
        \hline
        Something [Nr] & $\Delta\,y$ [m/s] & $\Delta x$  [s] &$a$ [m/s$^2$] \\
        \hline
        1.          & 0.6      & 2.4847 & 0.24148    \\
        2.          & 0.43     & 1.7630 & 0.24390    \\
        3.          & 0.38     & 1.5829 & 0.24007    \\
        4.          & 0.30     & 1.1617 & 0.25824    \\
        5.          & 0.45     & 1.8024 & 0.24967    \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Though normally x and y would be set in italics using maths mode: `$\Delta y$ [m/s]`etc. (sticking with the square brackets).

Comment: @ChrisH Of course you are right.  Pardon my omission.  Corrected.

Comment: As a remark on style my comment was addressed at least as much to the OP, but I appear to have become rather picky about such things.

Comment: @ChrisH That nit needed to be picked.  Keep it up.